# Update Resx files at runtime in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

My goal is to implement the changing values of resources and give the admin the ability to maintain the language through the portal. In order to do that, I need to be able to change resx files at the runtime, because all their values are stored on the resx files. I have 3 resx files for each different language. In my case I want the translation can be maintain later by an admin at runtime. For example admin can add, edit or delete the entry for the language at runtime.

Comment: You should maintain this in a database or similar instead of the resx/resource files if you want it to be modified at runtime. Those resource files are not intended to be modified in a running application.

Comment: @Xerillio I thought to use xml and dll files because even resx files are containers with xml data. So, first of all maybe a relation beetwen xml and dll can work perfectly !

Comment: Editing resx files at run time is not a practical option, after each change the app will recycle to recompile the new .resx file and create .resource file . Instead, you can use another file type or db, then export all at once to resx, at least app will be recycled once.

Comment: @LazZiya Is there any good source explanation (eg. link)  that can help me depending to your opinion?

Comment: @ErmalBaliu Your scenario is not very common, so I think you'll have a hard time finding good resources on doing this specifically. What's the reason you need to do this at runtime? It sounds like a lot of effort to support some functionality that's gonna be used once and then not touched again.

Answer (score 1):

As @Xerillio mentioned in his comment **this is a lot of effort.**

Recently I've created a nuget that may save your time and effort. Have a look at [XLocalizer](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer), it creates resources and uses [online translation services](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/translate-services.md) to auto translate the missing resources and save them in [XML](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/setup-xml.md) or [DB](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/setup-db.md), then it provides an easy interface to [export them to RESX](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/export-xml-to-resx.md). Finally you may see [XLocalizer.Samples](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer.Samples), it contains sample setup for different scenarios.

If you need another file/DB type to store the resources, you may create your [custom resource provider](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/using-custom-resource-provider.md) and register it in startup.

The [DB sample](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer.Samples/tree/master/DbLocalizationSample) provides UI to edit resources, but with [XML sample](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer.Samples/tree/master/XmlLocalizationSample) I didn't create a UI for editing resources, instead you may download the XML, do your corrections if any, then upload and use the built-in exporter to export to RESX.

With this nuget, all I have to do to add a new culture *even in runtime*, is just to add the culture name to the supported cultures list, then do some correction to the auto translations, all the rest is handled by [XLocalizer](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer).

*Notice: it was not possible to put all this in the comment, thats why I posted as answer :)*

Comment: Hello @LazZiya, thanks for answering.
I am not allowed to use another file type, so all I have to do is using these three .resx files for three different languages. The reason of doing this is all about these .resx files because they contains 2470 names and their relevant values. These resources names are then used generally in my project. The reason why I tend to do these runtime editing resources is that some users maybe do not like our preferences of resources that are created earlier, and so their Administrator can change these named resources in project at Runtime.

Comment: @ErmalBaliu "maybe do not like" does not sound like a very good motivation to add some functionality that requires a lot of effort to implement. If you're worried they dislike your translations, I suggest you invite those administrators to a meeting and have them do the translations/corrections once and for all and use that in your application. Don't overcomplicate things for yourself.